# Why is foldr' not as strict as foldl'?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, fold, strictness

Consider these various attempts at something that works like `last`:

```hs
Prelude> import Data.Foldable
Prelude Data.Foldable> foldr const undefined (reverse [1,2,3])
3
Prelude Data.Foldable> foldr' const undefined (reverse [1,2,3])
3
Prelude Data.Foldable> foldl (flip const) undefined [1,2,3]
3
Prelude Data.Foldable> foldl' (flip const) undefined [1,2,3]
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:5:21 in interactive:Ghci4
```

It makes sense to me that `foldl` and `foldr` both work, since they aren't strict in their accumulator, and it makes sense to me that `foldl'` doesn't, since it is. But why does `foldr'` work? Isn't it supposed to be strict in its accumulator too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, the instance `Foldable []` overrides `foldr`, `foldl`, `foldl'`, but not `foldr'` ([source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#line-308)):

```hs
instance Foldable [] where
    elem    = List.elem
    foldl   = List.foldl
    foldl'  = List.foldl'
    foldl1  = List.foldl1
    foldr   = List.foldr
    {- ... -}
```

`foldr'` is defined by default as ([source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#foldr%27)):

```hs
foldr' :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr' f z0 xs = foldl f' id xs z0
  where f' k x z = k $! f x z
```

**Note that there is only a strictness annotation on the result of `f`. So the initial accumulator is not forced.**

This suggests a different implementation which does force the accumulator:

```hs
foldr'' :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr'' f = foldr (\x z -> f x $! z)
```

(Edited: the previous version was specialized to lists.)

I have no idea why one was chosen over the other. Probably an oversight,
and it would be more consistent for `foldr'` to not use the default implementation in the `Foldable []` instance.

---

As an aside, the default definition of `foldl'` is also different from the list one in the same way:

```hs
-- Default (class Foldable t where ...)
foldl' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldl' f z0 xs = foldr f' id xs z0
  where f' x k z = k $! f z x

-- List implementation
foldl'           :: forall a b . (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl' k z0 xs =
  foldr (\(v::a) (fn::b->b) -> oneShot (\(z::b) -> z `seq` fn (k z v))) (id :: b -> b) xs z0
```

Comment: Your definition is specialized to lists, original one is for generic Foldable (with e.g. only lazy `foldr` defined). One could have `foldl f' id xs $! z0`, I guess. (I haven't try if it makes things "correctly" stricter).

Comment: That's a fair observation. Actually, out of the four `fold[lr]'?` variants, `foldr'` is the only one `Foldable []` does not override, leading to this inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Oh, that's weird indeed. (Given that Foldable is huge dictionary anyway, having one more method would make sense, especially in this case for Seq or SnocList).

Comment: I just changed the second definition to not be specific to lists.

Comment: For the definitions of `foldl'` and `foldr'` on generic `Foldable`s, it makes more sense for `foldl'` to be defined in terms of `foldr`, and for `foldr'` to be defined in terms of `foldl`. This is because you generally want `foldl'` to work something like a tail-recursive strict function (like for sums or whatever), and you cannot define that (on cons-lists) in terms of `foldl`. `foldr'` would function the same for snoc-lists. The generic definition on lists also benefits from the specialisation. There is no "good" version of `foldr'`, which is probably why a special version is not included.

Comment: To be clear, the fact that the overridden `List.foldl'` has a different strictness is probably is probably an oversight. I'm just explaining why some are overridden and some aren't.

Comment: Hysterical raisins. This inconsistency is one of Joachim Breitner's few mistakes. When he came up with how brilliant way to make `foldl` fuse nicely, he applied the same trick to `foldl'`. Unfortunately, when he did so, he accidentally made the function stricter.